# Unable to click on an element by using xpaht in Android (Appium)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Unable to click on an element by using `xpaht` on `Android 8.1.0/7.1.0`, but the same `xpath` working perfectly on `Android 10`

element like

```
By postBtn = By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Post']");
driver.findElement(postBtn).click();
```

Appium `v1.15.1`

java version `1.8.0_241`

selenium-java: `3.141.59`

java-client: `6.1.0`

Project type: `Maven project`

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Post')]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no luck, it's not working on Android 8.1.0

Comment: can you post your xml structure here, you can get it from Appium-desktop tool

Comment: most likely your app rendered differently on Android 8/7, e.g. element is not in viewport and can't be accessed